# Expected type parameter `T` found reference `&T`

Tags: rust

```
fn is_sublist<T: PartialEq>(_first_list: &[T], _second_list: &[T]) -> bool {
  if !_first_list.len() == 0 || !_second_list.len() == 0 {
     return false
  }
  let first_item = &_first_list[0];
  let first_len = _first_list.len();
  let mut iter = _second_list.iter();
  // Here i am getting error
  assert_eq!(iter.position(|&x| x == first_item), Some(1));

  return true
}
```

I am trying to find an index of the selected element, from the selected array. But I am getting an error of mismatched types. Why is this happens and how can i fix this?

Comment: Not related to your question, but, are you certain about the `if` at the beginning? As soon as one slice is not empty, the function returns `false`. I guess you meant the opposite (empty and empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your closure in line 9, with the pattern `|&x| ...` you're trying to move the argument out of a reference and into `x`. With type annotations this might become clearer: `|&x: &T| ...`. This means `x` has type `T`. But `first_item` is still a `&T`, meaning inside the closure, you're now trying to do `T == &T`, which isn't implemented. This is why you're getting the error that you're getting. This is easily fixed by just not moving out of the reference. The closure just needs to be `|x| ...`.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler complains that the Expected type parameter of function `iter.position` is `T`, but found reference `&T`

And the variable `first_item` you pass to `position` is a reference:

```rust
let first_item = &_first_list[0];
```

You could change it to this, as compiler suggests:

```rust
let first_item = _first_list[0];
```

Comment: This only works for copy types. You can't just move out of a shared reference.